# Where is the NAT adapter on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, nat

On my Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) guest in VirtualBox when I set the connection type to “Host only Adapter”, I can set the IP address of `vboxnet1` to what I want. But where is the NAT adapter?

Or a better way to say it: Is NAT an interface or not? If yes, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a screenshot of the VirtualBox NAT settings in Ubuntu 14.04. In order to show the Settings window shown in the screenshot, click the gear-shaped Settings icon ⚙️ in the VirtualBox toolbar

**Network Address Translation (NAT)** NAT enables the guest machine to see out onto the Internet, but via a private IP address that cannot be seen from the host, or indeed, the rest of your physical network. It will allow you to browse the web, download files and view email inside the guest, but the outside world will never be able to communicate with the guest machine directly.<sup>**1**</sup>

NAT is the default type of network attachment in VirtualBox.

Clicking anywhere in the type of network attachment field marked by the mouse cursor in the screenshot will show a dropdown menu of several types of network attachments, including NAT and Host-only Adapter.

[image]

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>[How-to: VirtualBox Networking - NAT and Bridged](https://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html)</sub>